# Add Managed metadata to link to a document

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata

I have a document library that contains both documents and links to documents.

How do I add managed metadata tags to the links to documents?

I have looked at the columns, which are below. It seems like there should be a way for Used In to be set for multiple content types(e.g. Document and Link to a Document).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to `Library Settings`
2. Click `Link to a Document` under **Content Types**
3. Click `Add from existing site or list columns`
4. Add your column (`metadata tag` in my case)

I liked this alternative better. I didn't have to create a new content type, and it only changes my Document Library rather than for the entire SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [create your own link to a document content type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-site-content-type-HA010097493.aspx) and extend it to add in your managed metadata column, then apply that to the library.

I wrote about it in [http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-2010-Work-Tricks-Opinions/dp/1449321003](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449321003)